# how can sending URL from other file

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have PrintHello this is my code

in  PrintHello.h

```
@interface PrintHello : UIViewController

-(void)Print;

@end
```

and PrintHello.m

```
-(void)Print
{

    [self URL];

}

-(void)URL
{
    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://arproject.site90.com/jsonbuilding.php"];
    NSLog(@"%@",strURL);
}
```

in viewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.printMessage = [[PrintHello alloc]init];
}

-(IBAction)Button01
{
    NSString *url=[self.printMessage Print];
    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];
    NSLog(@"%@",strURL);
}
```

what I misunderstood
i want to sending url from PrintHello 
I need to do?
please help
thank you

Comment: how you switch PrintHello to viewcontroller?

Comment: hey check the return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I don't see why `PrintHello` is derived from `UIViewController`; it looks like `NSObject` will do, and secondly you don't actually return anything from your methods (and thirdly, method names should start with a lowercase letter, by convention):

```
@interface PrintHello : NSObject

- (NSURL *)print;

@end

@implementation PrintHello

- (NSURL *)print
{
    return [self url];
}

- (NSURL *)url
{
    NSString *strURL = @"http://arproject.site90.com/jsonbuilding.php";
    NSLog(@"%@",strURL);
    return [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)URL{

}
```

should actually return type NSURL instead of a void.